# Controllers required for split screen Team Sonic Racing on Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, team-sonic-racing

If I want to play two player Team Sonic Racing in split screen mode (on Nintendo Switch) can one player use the left controller and the other use the right controller, or do we need to buy another full controller set for the second person?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use one joy con controller per player in Team Sonic Racing for split screen.

You need to make sure that the Switch has detected that this is your control scheme in the main menu before you start the game and then when you select 2 player it will work with one joy con per player like Mario Kart does.

Comment: This doesn't work. If it does, can you break it down step by step on how we use the left hand controller for one person and the right handed controller for another person on Nintendo Switch when there is **no main menu options** to change or add another player?

Comment: The main menu is the Nintendo Switch control scheme menu, where it shows you a picture of a switch and what controllers are assigned to each individual player like in every other game on the Switch.